# How do I avoid being seen in Gerudo fortress?

Tags: zelda-ocarina-of-time-3d

I am always seen please I really want to beat the game.

Comment: From what I remember, I think its really about timing.  That's about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're supposed to sneak around by staying hidden and out of sight.

Luckily, if sneaking is too difficult, there's still another way to explore the Gerudo Fortress.

- Shoot the guards with your Hookshot. This will stun them temporarily. If you've completed the Water Temple, you should have an upgraded version of the Hookshot with a longer reach.
- Shoot the guards with arrows. This will "kill" them until you get caught, or leave the area and return.

If you're concerned about wasting arrows killing the same guards over and over again, you can use the Hookshot to stun them, then hit them with your sword to kill them.

You can probably use other weapons too, but those are the most accurate ones which can be used safely from a distance. You're much more likely to get caught trying to hurl a bomb at the guards than shooting them from out of sight.